# Mediaelement source from server(mms:) problem wpf

Tags: wpf, mediaelement, playlist

mp3 files from server takes more than 5mins to play in the mediaelement.

Code:

```
  <MediaElement 
            Name="player" 
    Source="{Binding ElementName=lbTrack, Path=SelectedItem.FilePath, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
            UnloadedBehavior="Stop"
            Volume="{Binding ElementName=volume, Path=Value}" MediaEnded="player_MediaEnded" MediaOpened="player_MediaOpened" 
            LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get better performance from the ActiveX media player.  Try this walkthrough:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx